# WPF TabItem Customized Headers in Code?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabitem

I know in WPF, if I want to create a TabItem with a custom header with an image and text its very simple in XAML:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="header.png" />
            <TextBlock Text="Header" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
</TabItem>
```

However, I am not constructing my TabItems in XAML, I am doing it in code:

```
TabItem tab = new TabItem();
tab.Header = header;
tabControl.Items.Add(tab);
```

How would I program this custom header in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your XAML example, your `TabItem` could be constructed in code like this:

```
var tab = new TabItem();
var stack = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
stack.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("header.png", UriKind.Relative)) });
stack.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Header" });
tab.Header = stack;
```

Comment: The code `stack.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("header.png")) });` is failing...

Comment: The error I am getting is: Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Scoreboard_Assistant.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

Comment: Figured it out, I needed `UriKind.Relative`